# How can I replicate an Eureka Client?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, replication, netflix-eureka

I'm doing an app with Spring boot and Spring Cloud, have 2 microservices.  I'm using Eureka Server to register both microservices as a clients, but I want to replicate one of them.

How can I do that? I saw info on Google, but seems like I need to replicate Eureka Server, and I don't understand it.

Is it possible to replicate one eureka Client?

Thank you in advance!

I tried to replicate eureka server, but it's not the thing that I want to do. I want to replicate a client.

Comment: Can you be more specific by what you mean by "replicate one of them"? Eureka is built to handle multiple instances of a service by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Due to high demand, one of both microservices have to do two replications. I guess, it is the same that have 2 instances of same service

Comment: Just start a new instance of the service and everything should work just fine

Comment: Eureka is, in fact, built with many more instances of a service in mind than two. By default, if one of the two instances goes down, eureka will enter fail-safe mode and not remove instances when they go down because it will think there is a network problem.